# Изменение значений полей класса

Tags: python-3.x, qt5

Всем привет!

Имеется программа python3 + qt5.

Есть код:

```
class IM_MainFrame(QMainWindow):
   def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()
      self.initUI()
      self.taskList = []
      self.taskType = 0
      self.global_db_name = ''
```

Также класс содержит QTableWidget

```
self.masterTable = QTableWidget()
```

для которого задан обработчик выбора (в виде checkbox) элемента

```
self.masterTable.itemClicked.connect(self.handleItemClicked)
```

Так вот. Внутри этого handleItemClicked все значения полей класса self "обнуляются".

```
def handleItemClicked(self, item):
   print ('handleItemClicked:: db = {}'.format(self.global_db_name))
```

Здесь показывается, что self.global_db_name пустое, хотя оно точно задано.
Думал через lambda выражение сделать, но не знаю что задать вместо item здесь

```
self.masterTable.itemClicked.connect(lambda: self.handleItemClicked(item=????, db = self.global_db_name)
```

при этом

```
def handleItemClicked(self, item, db):
```

Comment: `Здесь показывается, что self.global_db_name пустое, хотя оно точно задано.` и в `__init__`: `self.global_db_name = '' ` Ну да, пустое

Comment: Ахаха, человек, спасибо. Я 2 часа искал ошибку.

class IM_MainFrame(QMainWindow):
   def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()
      self.taskList = []
      self.taskType = 0
      self.global_db_name = '' 
      self.initUI()